# how to merge collections in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a newbie at rails and i wanted help on how to merge collections of two active record objects?

An article has many comments

```
class Article < Content

  has_many :comments
```

I want to create a new article with comments merged from the comments of source and target article objects.Below, source_id and target_id are ids of two Articles. I want to get comments from them and merge them and add to the new article.

```
 source_id = params[:id]
 target_id = params[:merge_with]


 @article = Article.get_or_build_article()

 @article.allow_comments = true

 article_source = Article.find(source_id)
 article_target = Article.find(target_id)


 #reassign all comments of first article 
 first_comments = article_source.comments

 first_comments.each do |c|

   c.article_id = @article.id
   c.save

 end


 #reassign all comments of second article
 second_comments = article_target.comments

 second_comments.each do |d|

   d.article_id = @article.id
   d.save

 end


 @article.title = article_source.title

 @article.body = article_source.body + " " + article_target.body

 @article.author = article_source.author

 @article.save
```

I see that the new article is created but it doesnt display any comments. So, the linking is broken somewhere. I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: What are you doing in `get_or_build_article` method? are you returning a  saved object  or a new object which is not persisted in database?

Comment: just a new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not saved @article in database. So @article.id is nil.

```
first_comments.each do |c|

   c.article_id = @article.id
   c.save

 end
```

So this loop, assigns nil to c.article_id. So first save the @article then update comments. Also use update_all for updating comments instead of looping.

```
  source_id = params[:id]
  target_id = params[:merge_with]


  @article = Article.get_or_build_article()

  @article.allow_comments = true

  article_source = Article.find(source_id)
  article_target = Article.find(target_id)

  @article.title = article_source.title

  @article.body = article_source.body + " " + article_target.body

  @article.author = article_source.author

  @article.save

  #reassign all comments of first article 
  first_comments = article_source.comments

  first_comments.update_all(article_id: @article.id)


  #reassign all comments of second article
  second_comments = article_target.comments

  second_comments.update_all(article_id: @article.id)
```

Or even better to update comments use this

```
Comment.where(article_id: [article_source.id, article_target.id]).update_all(article_id: @article.id)
```

Comment: Actually i had to add the collection entries to collection of new article like  second_comments.each do |d|
       
       @article.comments << d
       
       
     end

Comment: assigning article_id for the comment wasn't enough.